# Помогите добавить js запрос

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="admin";
$password="passadmin";
$db="admin";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error());
$db_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$db_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_query);
?>
<script>
   function getBanner() {
      // AJAX запрос
   }

   setInterval(getBanner, 10000); // Функция getBanner будет выполнятся каджые 30 сек
</script>

<?php echo $db_data['name']; ?>
```

Помогите что бы каждые 10 секунд он обновлял строчку name из базы данных

Comment: в смысле "напишите за меня ajax запрос и серверный обработчик" ?

Comment: @svoloch196, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Пробовал делать много раз, нужно вот что: что бы каждые 10 секунд он новые строки получал из базы данных, допустим у меня в безе данных 100 записей и он должен каждые 10 секунд их менять и так до бесконечности у меня это работает только при обновлении страницы

Comment: @svoloch196 нам понятно что вам нужно, непонятно почему вы хотите чтобы мы за вас это написали. попробуйте сделать, даже неработающий пример, а мы подскажем что неправильно. сейчас неправильно - у вас нет кода который посылает ajax запрос и обрабатывает его на сервере.

Comment: Пробовал вот так сделать:
   function getBanner() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'api.php',
  success: function(){
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
   }
   setInterval(getBanner, 1000);

Comment: @svoloch196, зачем сколько кода который никому не нужен (я про тот код что в вопросе)?
Давайте так..:
Ваш api.php должен возвращать всего одну строку (даже одно слово) содержащее ваше поле name.
Следовательно получается что этот код если убрать из него джаваскрипт и есть ваш обработчик api.php
В том месте где вам нужно запускать ваш ротатор у вас должно быть что-то похожее на 
$.ajax({
        url: "api.php",
        success: function(data) {
                $("#banner").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
Однако нужно знать реальную задачу а вы ее не посвящаете нам :(

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp